# How to correctly hide BottomAppbar in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to hide my bottom appBar in other fragments, so it cannot be visible. I tried to do it in this way

```java
public void hideBottomMenu() {
    appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fabAdd.hide();
}
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: screenshot from screen]

[image: Screenshot from layout inspector]

But it doesn't work correctly, in my view, it becomes invisible, but when I'm scrolling some sort of view appears in the bottom of the screen (neither visibility of bottom app bar is gone).

Here is my MainActivity layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:menu="@menu/top_menu"
            app:title="Реєстр ТТН" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flInternetAbsent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E36363"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:letterSpacing="0.05"
                android:text="Відсутній інтернет"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways for this (that I don't like none of them). I prefer to setup bottom bar inside of fragments because in most fragments I don't use it. So for a handful of fragments this is fine.

**The second way** is same as your approach. Note that it is important to set visibility in this order (I've achieved this through try and error after days of hopeless approaches.): first hide FAB (using `fab.hide()`) then invisible it (I do this just to be sure that it will not appear anymore. using `fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)`) , then Invisible BottomBar (using `bottomAppBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)`). in Summary:

```
    public void hideBottomMenu() {
        fabAdd.hide();
        fabAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE); do not use this. it is a child of bottombar.
    }
```

For showing these components define:

```
    public void showBottomMenu() {
        appBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        appBarLayout.performShow();
        //fabAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // I am not sure about this.
        fabAdd.show();
        //bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE); do not use this. it is a child of bottombar.
    }
```

Then in `onCreate` method of fragments that you want to hide bottomBar, call it as

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).hideBottomMenu();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still leaves this shady bottomAppBar in my fragments? which appears only after scrolling. ps. fabAdd.setVisibility(View.GONE); is VisibilityAvareImageButton, and this method cannot be called for floating action button

Comment: dear pertalGad: Where is the fragment tag in your provided layout?

Comment: In your provided layout there is no fragment. I thought your problem is hiding bottom bar. but now I see that you have a RelativeLayout with margin 55dp. change it to padding and Add this line to it and you will see that the white space will disappear. 
                `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: oh.... my bad, it was just because of this margin, so stupid... thx for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use this listener. When destination changed in your navigation, your bottom app bar will gonna visible or gone.

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if (destination.id != R.id.id_selected_fragment) {
        binding.bottomBar.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        binding.bottomBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```